# Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined on Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

this is my code:

```
if(!member.guild.me.hasPermission('SEND_MESSAGES')) return;
```

according to discord.js.org's documention it's fine, and up till now anyone i asked didn't know the answer, what's the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Whatever `me` is it's `undefined`. Use your debugger to trace your code, find out why it's not being set to what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=me), yes, me is a property of guild, but it can be **undefined**.

> .me
>
> The client user as a GuildMember of this guild
>
> Type: ?GuildMember

From the [code](https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/Guild.js#L328),

```
get me() {
    return this.members.get(this.client.user.id);
}
```

If `this.client.user.id` is undefined, or not in the `guild`, you will get undefined returned and therefore, no property `hasPermission`.  The easiest way to figure out would be **debugging**.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the command

`if (!message.guild) return;`

to the code